# Check if a specific Linux Terminal is already open

Tags: linux, terminal, centos7, tail, mate-desktop

We have a Server Startup Script that is calling a Mate Terminal (or GNOME Terminal - should not make a difference) as Part of the Server Startup process which is, in essence, tailing the Servers info log like that:

```
mate-terminal --title="APPSERVER LOG" --working-directory=$SERVER_LOCATION --hide-menubar -e "sh -c 'tail -f --retry -n 400 ./server.log'" &
```

Now as you might imagine, while developing one ends up with quite a couple of open terminals all tailing the same logfile at the end of the day, caused by several server restarts.

Now my quastion: Is it possible to somehow check the open terminals for a specific running command, a specific title or similar, to only open a new terminal if there is not already one tailing?

I checked the man pages of mate-terminal but could not find anything that does any Window Management.

We are running CentOS7 and MATE 1.12.1

```
cat /etc/*release
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

Comment: You could try to grep pid of terminal from ps -ax. If pid exists, terminal is opened, else is not. I hope I understood well what you want to do.

Comment: @kitz see my comment in your question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to grep pid of mate like this:

```
pgrep -d " " -f path/to/mate/terminal/binary
```

And from there you decide if is necessary to open another, kill existing one, or whatever you want :)

Comment: the thing is that `ps aux | grep "mate-terminal"` only lists one mate-terminal instance, despite I currently have >10 Terminal Windows open...?  

`$ ps aux | grep mate-terminal
    user+ 26601  0.1  0.2 620616 25924 ?        Sl   10:40   0:02 mate-terminal --working-directory=/home -e sh -c "./skript"`

 `pgrep` also only lists the pid of one terminal, which is not the one that I am looking for. So it seems like MATE does not spawn new processeses for each Terminal Window?

Comment: Ok my bad, the way we call the tail via `sh -c` will result in the tail being listed as 

`user+ 26697  0.0  0.0 107932   688 pts/1    Ss+  10:40   0:00 tail -f --retry -n 400 ./server.log`

hence no hit for "mate" or "mate-terminal". Anyways I should be able to grep for the right tail. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth: Based on @kitz Answer I now ended up to not use `pgrep` to get a process id and not open a new tailing window, but rather use `pkill` to close the existing one and tail again. The reason is, that the logfile might have been deleted in the meantime, so even with `--retry`, which only works for the initial open, the original tail might have lost the log.

So this is it:

```
TAILCMD="tail -f --retry -n 400 ./server.log"
pkill -ef "$TAILCMD"
mate-terminal --title="Server Log" --working-directory=$SERVER_LOCATION --hide-menubar -e "sh -c '${TAILCMD}'" &
```

Thanks again @kitz for pointing me in the right direction!